# Display Created Date DateTime field as DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS (am/pm) in record detail page

Tags: page-layout, datetime, detail-page, format, work-order

I've been trying to figure out how to display **Created Date** field with the format:
**DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS [AM/PM]**

By default, Salesforce displays it as **DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM [AM/PM]**. See picture below.

I'm confused as Salesforce already stores datetime values together with seconds but is not displaying them in details page.

Do I need to create a new formula field just to format Created Date there?
Appreciate the help to complete this requirement efficiently. Thanks!

[image: Created Date displayed in Salesforce Work Order detail page by default.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment formula field will be your best option. I can see there is an open [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhamUAB/display-ss-in-datetime-fields) regarding this, known to Salesforce which you can vote up.